# Execute Maven SQL Plug-in on Multiple Databases

Tags: maven

We have a pretty common use case (I assume), where we use the `sql-maven-plugin` to create a database for an integration test, then later drop it.

Now I needed to initialize said database as well, so the final set-up looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>

    <configuration>
        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create_database</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://${db.integration.url}:postgres</url>
                <sqlCommand>CREATE DATABASE ${db.integration.name} ENCODING = 'UTF8';</sqlCommand>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>init_database</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://${db.integration.url}:${db.integration.name}</url>
                <srcFiles>
                    <srcFile>create_database.sql</srcFile>
                </srcFiles>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>drop_database</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://${db.integration.url}:postgres</url>
                <sqlCommand>DROP DATABASE ${db.integration.name}</sqlCommand>
                <onError>continue</onError>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, all three executions of the plug-in are done on the **same** database (`postgres` in this case), whereas I wanted to have the middle one be executed on the freshly created database (whatever is behind the variable `${db.integration.name}`).

How do I fix this set-up?

Comment: Try to add `<autocommit>true</autocommit>` on `create_database` execution.

Comment: @Tunaki That property is set to true (I just tried to clean the XML up a bit and removed it).